# Postgresql raises 'data directory has wrong ownership' when trying to use volume

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run postgresql in docker container, but of course I need to have my database data to be persistent, so I'm trying to use data only container which expose volume to store database at this place.

So, my data container has such Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Create data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/postgresql

# Create /data volume
VOLUME /data/postgresql
```

Which I run:

```
docker run --name postgresql_data lyapun/postgresql_data true
```

In my postgresql.conf I set:

```
data_directory = '/data/postgresql'
```

Then I run my postgresql container in such way:

```
docker run -d --name postgre --volumes-from postgresql_data lyapun/postgresql
```

And I got:

```
2014-07-04 07:45:57 GMT FATAL:  data directory "/data/postgresql" has wrong ownership
2014-07-04 07:45:57 GMT HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

How to deal with this issue? I googled a lot to find some information about using postgresql with docker volumes, but I didn't found anything.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting postgres?

Comment: CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"]

Comment: Are you running that as the user, `postgres`?

Comment: yes.

    USER postgres

    EXPOSE 5432

    CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"]

Comment: In my case, I had the data directory mounted on an external hard disk. File format was different in the external hard disk. I started giving the mount directory to the home location and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found workaround for this issue.

Instead of running postgres in such way:

```
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

I wrote bash script:

```
chown -Rf postgres:postgres /data/postgresql
chmod -R 700 /data/postgresql
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

And replaced CMD in postgresql image to:

```
CMD ["bash", "/run.sh"]
```

It works!

Comment: Are you sure? I notice that you are still using `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main` as your data folder and not the mounted volume `/data/postgresql`. So the data is still being saved in the container.

Answer (score 2):

This type of errors is quite common when you link a NTFS directory into your docker container. NTFS directories don't support ext3 file & directory access control.
The only way to make it work is to link directory from a ext3 drive into your container.

I got a bit desperate when I played around Apache / PHP containers with linking the www folder. After I linked files reside on a ext3 filesystem the problem disappear.

I published a short Docker tutorial on youtube, may it helps to understand this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS9O05TTFjM

Comment: The video is not available anymore...

Comment: Your answer is correct. I moved my docker to ntfs and it denied to run postgres on it. So I had to change my volume's mount point to ext3 device directory. This asnwer helped me to finish the investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55952189/7744106

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ownership of directory /data/postgresql to the same user, under which you are running your postgresql binary. For example, in Ubuntu it is usually `postgres` user.

Then you have to use this command:

```
chown postgres.postgres /data/postgresql
```

Comment: In which Dockerfile should I do this? I tried and this didn't help

Comment: @lyapun to be honest, I don't know docker. But I think, that you can do that, when you creating a volume...

Comment: thanks but user postgres created in container which expose volume will be different to user postgres which created in postgresql container.

Comment: @lyapun try to run command `id postgres` in the same container, as you run `postgresql` in it. You will see numerical uid and gid. Then use this numerical uid/gid instead of `postgres` values in the `chown` command.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to solve that issue, assuming your postgres images is named "postgres" and that your backup is ./backup.tar:

First, add this to your postgres Dockerfile:

```
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

Then run:

```sh
docker run -it --name postgres -v $(pwd):/db postgres sh -c "tar xvf /db/backup.tar --no-overwrite-dir" && \
docker run -it --name data --volumes-from postgres busybox true && \
docker rm postgres && \
docker run -it --name postgres --volumes-from=data postgres
```

You don't have permission issues since the archive is extracted by the postgres user of your postgres image, so it is the owner of the extracted files.
You can then backup your data using the data container. The advantage of this solution is that you don't chmod/chown every time you run the image.

Answer (score 0):

the host directory owner ID must be the same Postgres user ID in the container if you checked the Dockerfile in the source code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq28R.png)

so you can simply create the same group and the same user on the host and change the ownership of the volume host directory to postgres user:

```
groupadd -r postgres --gid=999
useradd -r -g postgres --uid=999 --home-dir=/var/lib/postgresql --shell=/bin/bash postgres
sudo chown -R postgres:posgres /data/postgresql
```