# How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a development environment I'm dockerizing and I would like the ability to livereload my changes without having to rebuild docker images. I'm using docker compose because redis is one of my app's dependencies and I like being able to link a redis container

I have two containers defined in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
node:
  build: ./node
  links:
    - redis
  ports:
    - "8080"
  env_file:
    - node-app.env

redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379"
```

I've gotten to the point in my `node` app's dockerfile where I add a volume, but how do I mount the the host's directory in the volume so that all my live edits to the code are reflected in the container?

Here's my current Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM    node:boron

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Amin Shah Gilani <amin@gilani.me>

# Install nodemon
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Add a /app volume
VOLUME ["/app"]

# TODO: link the current . to /app

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Run npm install
RUN npm install

# Expose port
EXPOSE  8080

# Run app using nodemon
CMD ["nodemon", "/app/app.js"]
```

My project looks like this:

```
/
- docker-compose.yml
- node-app.env
- node/
  - app.js
  - Dockerfile.js
```

Answer (score 408, accepted):

<s>Checkout their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)</s>

From the looks of it you could do the following on your docker-compose.yml

```yaml
volumes:
    - ./:/app
```

Where `./` is the host directory, and `/app` is the target directory for the containers.

---

EDIT:
Previous documentation source now leads to version history, you'll have to select the version of compose you're using and look for the reference.

For the lazy – [v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3) / [v2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#short-syntax) / [v1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#volumes-volume_driver)

Side note: Syntax remains the same for all versions as of this edit

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work: `Error: Cannot find module '/data/app.js'`

Comment: wait.. your VOLUME and WORKDIR points to `/app/` why is your CMD pointing to `/data`

Comment: That was an error! Thank you for catching that! Fixed, and now I get `Error: Cannot find module 'express'` I'm gonna try a few things now.

Comment: For windows containers, you'll want a windows style path like `- .:c:/app` (this tripped me up)

Comment: I have lots of stuff in my current directory but the volume directory has nothing in it.

    volumes:
      - .:/stocks

Comment: There's no mention of `volume` in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: Does this `volumes` belong to `services` section or stand alone section?

Comment: Side note. If you need to mount 1 dir above the host dir, just use standard `..` syntax: `- ../:/app` works on Linux containers and `- ..\:\app` works on Windows containers. At least it works with Docker engine 20.10.11 for me.

Comment: Follow-on to @jrbe228's comment: In the the case that your docker-compose YAML file is not in your current directory (i.e., you're using docker-compose's `-f` option), `./` will refer to the directory containing the YAML file.

Answer (score 256):

There are a few options

### Short Syntax

Using the `host : guest` format you can do any of the following:

```yaml
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

### Long Syntax

As of docker-compose v3.2 you can use long syntax which allows the configuration of additional fields that can be expressed in the short form such as `mount type` (volume, bind or tmpfs) and `read_only`.

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./static
        target: /opt/app/static

networks:
  webnet:

volumes:
  mydata:
```

Check out https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3 for more info.

Comment: To add to your answer, there are also `:cached` and `:delegated` annotations in the short syntax. These matter if the host is Docker Desktop for Mac. They are documented in https://docker-docs.netlify.app/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/ but unfortunately not in the Docker Compose docs.

Comment: @RominRonin the website xy2401.com looks suspicious.

Answer (score 122):

If you would like to mount a particular host directory (`/disk1/prometheus-data` in the following example) as a volume in the `volumes` section of the Docker Compose YAML file, you can do it as below, e.g.:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus

volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /disk1/prometheus-data
```

By the way, in prometheus's Dockerfile, You may find the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) instruction as below, which marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host, etc. (Note however: this instruction is not a must though to mount a volume into a container.):

**Dockerfile**

```dockerfile
...
VOLUME ["/prometheus"]
...
```

Refs:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Where is the documentation for the `local` driver type?

Comment: @mmell The documentation is the first Refs link (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver) It reads: Specify which volume driver should be used for this volume. Defaults to whatever driver the Docker Engine has been configured to use, which in most cases is `local`

Comment: @mmell, you can find more details from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195334/docker-compose-volumes-driver-local-meaning

Comment: How did you know the settings in ```driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none```?

Comment: @mmell Basically, those options are driver-dependent, and the built-in `local` driver on Linux accepts options similar to the linux mount command: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html. You can find more discussion at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19990#issuecomment-248955005, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841241/docker-compose-named-mounted-volume

Comment: @JackNavaRow, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212086/error-docker-compose-docker-windows/41216551#41216551

Comment: @Yuci  it works in window, i added a litle configuration , I hope that you accept it, thanks bro!

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one for a separate question about how to mount a host directory across multiple containers; twas hard to find this!

Comment: @jiminikiz I entirely agree -- this saved my bacon. I tried to do a bit more of a formal writeup here: https://aaronpung.wordpress.com/2022/06/07/docker-demos-populating-a-shared-volume-with-a-local-directory/

Answer (score 19):

It was two things:

I added the volume in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
node:
  volumes:
    - ./node:/app
```

I moved the `npm install && nodemon app.js` pieces into a `CMD` because `RUN` adds things to the Union File System, and my volume isn't part of UFS.

```dockerfile
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM    node:boron

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER Amin Shah Gilani <amin@gilani.me>

# Install nodemon
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Add a /app volume
VOLUME ["/app"]

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Expose port
EXPOSE  8080

# Run npm install
CMD npm install && nodemon app.js
```

Answer (score 15):

we have to **create** your own **docker volume** mapped with the **host directory** before we **mention** in the **docker-compose.yml** as **external**

1.Create volume named ***share***

```bash
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=none \
--opt device=/home/mukundhan/share \
--opt o=bind share
```

2.Use it in your docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3"

volumes:
  share:
    external: true

services:
  workstation:
    container_name: "workstation"
    image: "ubuntu"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - share:/share:consistent
      - ./source:/source:consistent
    working_dir: /source
    ipc: host
    privileged: true
    shm_size: '2gb'
  db:
    container_name: "db"
    image: "ubuntu"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - share:/share:consistent
    working_dir: /source
    ipc: host
```

This way we can share the same directory with many services running in different containers

Comment: why do I need to have ipc: host ?

Comment: that is only needed when we need to bind the network into host itself.

Answer (score 11):

In docker-compose.yml you can use this format:

```
volumes:
    - host directory:container directory
```

according to their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

Comment: Does this `volume` belongs to `services` section or stand alone section?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working example for Node.js application and MongoDB database :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services: 
    my-app:
        container_name: my-app-container
        restart: always
        build: .
        volumes:
            - './storage:/usr/src/app/storage'
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        links:
            - my-app-db
    
    my-app-db:
        container_name: my-app-db-container
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - './data:/data/db'          
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.13.2
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sharing redis golang `docker-compose.yaml`. Using bind-mount I've achieved it.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  redisdb:
    image: redis:6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    container_name: redisdb-container
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redisdb", "--port", "6379"]

  urlshortnerservice:
    depends_on:
      - redisdb
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    restart: always
    container_name: url-shortner-container
    image: url-shortner-service
    volumes:
      - ../pkg/repository/filestorage:/pkg/repository/filestorage #host directory:container directory
```