# ERROR - Docker-compose/docker Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I wanted to deploy my application on a windows system. I recently (yesterday) installed `DockerToolbox-1.12.4` on my windows 10. This gives my a new terminal. When I tried to deploy my projet with `docker-compose up --build`, I receive this massage:

1. `ERROR: for myservice Cannot create container for myService: create
       \var\run\docker.socker: "\\var\\run\\docker.sock" includes invalid
       characters for a local volume name, only "[...][...]" are allowed` this service contains

and an other error is:

2. `ERROR: for service2 Cannont create container for service service2:
   Invalid bind mount spec
   "c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\project\\service2:/home/docker/code:rw"
   Encountered errors while bringing up projet`. My project has 4 containers and there is not error message for the 2 others.

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  s1:
    build: ../images/s1
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    links: ["s2"]
  s2:
    build: ../images/s2
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
  service2:
    build: ../images/service2
    ports:
     - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ../images/service2:/home/docker/code
  myService:
    build: ../images/myService
    ports:
     - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

What should I do to make this  works ?
 Can you please help to solve this ?

my docker version is : `docker version 1.12.4, build 1564f02`
my docker-compose version is : `docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` in your environment. See:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4240
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4253

Answer (score 20):

This example works for me:

```yaml
  test_dev:
    image: test/node:7.9
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - //c/Users/user/Sources:/usr/src/app/
    command:
     node /usr/src/app/start.js
```

Comment: I am using WSL1 and I'm running docker-compose from it. I was thinking that I can simply use UNIX paths referencing but only your solution worked for me. Thanks a lot, however I think it's a temporary workaround for Windows.

Comment: I can't edit above unfortuanately. Maybe will be useful for somebody: [long-syntax for volumes](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/10830/19719) from [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3)

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues trying to run `docker-compose build` on windows 10.
Error: 'Failed to execute script docker-compose'

After trying so many things and finally ran docker quick start terminal which ran Bash shell. I ran `cmd` command to switch to cmd and tryied the build command. That's it. Worked for me