# Volume binding using docker compose on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I recently upgraded my Docker Toolbox on Windows 10, and now my volume mounts no longer work. I've tried everything. Here is the current mount path:

```
volumes:
  - C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\backend:/var/www/html
```

I receive an invalid bind mount error.

Answer (score 57):

Use:

```
volumes:
  - "C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/backend:/var/www/html"
```

Putting the whole thing in double quotes and using forward slashes worked for me.
I was on windows 10 in windows 10 using Linux containers through WSL2

This answer was from Spenhouet given [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151#issuecomment-662343075).

Comment: this works if there are no spaces in the windows file path.

Comment: Confirmed. Even for a relative like "./backend:/app" the double quotes were necessary.

Answer (score 33):

1. Share nfs path using docker settings

[image]
2. execute following command

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data
```

3. Set path in docker compose file as shown below
   [image]
4. File copied to windows

[image]

Comment: Please note that step one is only needed in Hyper-V mode as noted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346254

Answer (score 12):

I think you have to set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212086/error-docker-compose-docker-windows/41216551#41216551).

Docker Machine should do it automatically: https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/3830

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me, in docker-compose.yml :

```
    volumes:
      - c/Users/Cyril/django:/mydjango
```

(Windows 10 with WSL2 and Docker Desktop)

Answer (score 5):

On windows 10, solved the problem with adding the last one `/` at the end of host and mount path, like that:

```
volumes:
  - '/c/work/vcs/app/docker/i18n/:/usr/app/target/i18n/'
```

Without adding **the last one `/`** mounted path contained some docker system folders and symlinks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using an absolute path located inside `C:\Users` dir, that didn't work for me either, and if you are using `Docker-Toolbox` see below.

### Overview

Forwarding the `./` relative path in `volumes` section will automatically get resolved by `docker-compose` to the directory containing `docker-compose.yml` file (for example, if your project is in `%UserProfile%/my-project` then `./:/var/www/html` gets `/c/Users/my-name/my-project:/var/www/html`).

The problem is that currently (using `DockerToolbox-19.03.1`) only the `/c/Users` directory gets shared with the Virtual-Machine (toolbox puts `docker` itself in the VM, which means it has no access to your file system, except mounted shared-directories).

### Conclusion

So, basically placing your project there (`C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME`) should make `./` work.
But **not even that worked** for me, and we ended up with below `_prepare.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

VBoxManage='/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage'

# Defines variables for later use.
ROOT=$(dirname $0)
ROOT=$(cd "$ROOT"; pwd)
MACHINE=default
PROJECT_KEY=shared-${ROOT##*/}

# Prepares machine (without calling "docker-machine stop" command).
#
if [ $(docker-machine status $MACHINE 2> /dev/null) = 'Running' ]; then
    echo Unmounting volume: $ROOT
    eval $(docker-machine env $MACHINE)
    docker-compose down
    docker-machine ssh $MACHINE <<< '
        sudo umount "'$ROOT'";
    '
    "$VBoxManage" sharedfolder remove $MACHINE --name "$PROJECT_KEY" -transient > /dev/null 2>&1
else
    docker-machine start $MACHINE
    eval $(docker-machine env $MACHINE)
fi

set -euxo pipefail
"$VBoxManage" sharedfolder add $MACHINE --name "$PROJECT_KEY" --hostpath "$ROOT" -automount -transient


docker-machine ssh $MACHINE <<< '
    echo Mounting volume: '$ROOT';
    sudo mkdir -p "'$ROOT'";
    sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 "'$PROJECT_KEY'" "'$ROOT'";
'

docker-compose up -d
docker-machine ssh $MACHINE
bash
```

**Usage:**

- Place a copy of it beside each project's `docker-compose.yml` file.
- Run it each time the system is turned on (simply double-click it or its shortcut).
- Done! relative paths should now work even if your project is in another drive (far away and outside of `C:\Users` dir).

**Note:**

- With a little edit, it should work without `docker-compose` being required.
- Consider running `docker system prune` to free disk-space (or simply add `docker system prune --force` to the above script, on a new line right after `mount` command).

Answer (score 4):

this work on my computer:

```
  mongoservice:
    image : mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - //d/tests/leaflet_data/mongo_data/:/data/db
    ports:
     - "27018:27017"
    expose:
     - "27017"
```

it will put mongo database to d:\tests\leaflet_data\mongo_data

But the best solution for me to do it like this:

```
volumes: 
      - ./mongo_data/:/data/db
```

This will put mongo db into the same folder where your docker-compose yml file live. It will create mongo_data in this working dir.
Very convenient, just put everything you need in project directory.

Answer (score 3):

I faced with same issue (I'm using Docker Desktop).

**My steps were:**

1) Place your folder under drive "C"

2) Open "Settings" in Docker Desktop -> "Shared Drives" -> "Reset Credentials" -> select drive "C" -> "Apply"

3) Open terminal and run (as proposed by Docker Desktop):
`docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data`

4) Open your `docker-compose.yml` and update path in `-volumes`:

```
volumes:
  - /data/YOUR_USERNAME/projects/my_project/jssecacerts:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts/
```

5) restart docker container

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new Docker WSL2 backend, some drives may not be mounted in any WSL (and so Docker won't be able to see them either). For example, D: or E: or usb drives. See

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151
- https://superuser.com/questions/1114341/windows-10-ubuntu-bash-shell-how-do-i-mount-other-windows-drives

To rule out this problem, try running docker-compose from a `wsl` command line.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing `:` and '' in the windows path with `/` at the first of the line.

to be like that:

```
 volumes:
      -/c/Users/Joey/Desktop/backend:/var/www/html
```

Please note: `c` should be small.