# Installed docker for desktop . i cant find shared folder options in settings

Tags: windows, docker, directory, desktop, shared

I installed docker for desktop windows. Created docker file and ran simple nodejs call. it works. Issue now is shared folder. There is no option in settings. Actually i dont see most options people see in them. Without shared folder its not easy to develpp apps. I use visual code. So i need a shared folder that can be used between linux docker container and windows 10 file directory. Any one help?

I google searched i cant find it anywhere. it seems like every one use docker in perfect condition?

Comment: Are you expecting your **live code changes** to reflect in **docker container** via `shared folder`?

Answer (score 20):

Please see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

It states:

> The File sharing tab is only available in Hyper-V mode, because in WSL
> 2 mode and Windows container mode all files are automatically shared
> by Windows.

I think this is what you are looking for. I also wasted too much time looking for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but as @Frank Monroe pointed out, you need to enable hyper V on your machine, open your PowerShell console as administrator then paste the below command. Restart your machine then go back to the docker settings uncheck the "use the WSL 2 based engine" as indicated in the image, once your docker is restart then you'll be able to see the file sharing option [image]

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

Note: run the Powershell not the normal windows command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "volumes": https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

To enable that option, you need to switch to Windows containers and for that you need a Windows 10 pro o enterprise build:
[image]

To check Windows Version:
Open Run with **WIN + R** and launch command **winver**:
[image]

[image]