# run linux containers on windows server 2019

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, redis

I'm trying to run Redis and ElasticSearch containers on windows server 2019. But I get error.

Here is my docker compose :

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    command: redis-server --requirepass 1234Abcd?!
    ports:
     - "6339:6379"
    volumes:
      - /volumes/redis/data:/data
    networks:
     - marketland 

  elasticsearch:
   image: elasticsearch:7.6.2
   volumes:
     - /volumes/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   volumes:
      - "esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
   hostname: elasticsearch
   ports:
     - "9200:9200"
   environment:
     - discovery.type=single-node
     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
   ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
   networks:
     - marketland
     
  kibana:
   image: kibana:7.6.2
   ports:
     - "5601:5601"
   depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
   environment:
     - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
     - SERVER_NAME=kibana
   networks:
     - marketland
networks:
  marketland:
    external: true
volumes:
  esdata:
```

and after execute docker-compose -f docker-compose-pre up, I get this error :

```
Creating services_redis_1 ...
Creating services_elasticsearch_1 ... error
Creating services_redis_1         ... error
ERROR: for services_elasticsearch_1  Cannot create container for service elasticsearch: invalid option: Windows does not support Ulimits

ERROR: for services_redis_1  Cannot create container for service redis: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 6821998c02d7861bd5fd6ca679dedcf30f9de574485632daed57d8fc872ae323_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"6821998c02d7861bd5fd6ca679dedcf30f9de574485632daed57d8fc872ae323_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true})

ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot create container for service elasticsearch: invalid option: Windows does not support Ulimits

ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 6821998c02d7861bd5fd6ca679dedcf30f9de574485632daed57d8fc872ae323_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"6821998c02d7861bd5fd6ca679dedcf30f9de574485632daed57d8fc872ae323_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"kernel"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true})
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Is there any way to run these containers on Windows Server 2019 ?

** Hyper-v has already enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem with the Redis container on Windows Server 2019. Do you have any news? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set ulimit in windows. Remove below lines:

```
ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
```

It will only solve your elasticsearch problem.
I recommend to try to use docker on linux.

Answer (score 0):

As per hamid bayat remove `ulimits`.

The container-to-host volume bindings for both the redis & ElasticSearch containers also looks incorrect for Windows. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334021/volume-binding-using-docker-compose-on-windows) SO for how the volumes should be defined in Windows. e.g.

Instead of:

```
volumes:
   /volumes/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

should be something like:

```
volumes:
   - "C:/volumes/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
```

Note: you've also got duplicate `volumes` in the ElasticSearch container - you can put both under a single one e.g.

Instead of:

```
volumes:
   - /volumes/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
volumes:
   - "esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
```

Should be:

```
volumes:
   - /volumes/elastic/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   - "esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using windows10/Home and Linux Container, the `docker-complse.yml` below works fine for me, try it

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/usr/share/Redis/data

  elastic_search:
    container_name: ElasticSearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - ./es-data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment: 
    - discovery.type=single-node
```