# Trying to execute a docker-compose file on windows but get error my bind mount config is incorrect

Tags: mysql, windows, docker-compose

I am trying to execute a docker-compose file on windows but it says that my bind mount config is incorrect

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
 database:
  image: 'mysql:latest' 
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
  ports: 
    - '3306:3306'
  expose: 
    - '3306'
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: C:\Users\CY\composetest\data\mysql
      target: '/var/lib/mysql'
 application:
  image: 'dataiku/dss:latest'
  ports: 
    - '10000:10000'
  volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\Users\CY\composetest\data\dss
        target: '/home/dataiku/dss'
```

Comment: I think this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41334021