# persist %USERPROFILE% folder using docker compose volume

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am searching on how to persist user profile folder in volume mounting

I have folder C:\Users\ABEL\source\repos which needs to be persisted for a windows container. The username should be from the host. It is unknown.

Below is my docker-compose file, The volume section is not correct.
Any comments will be helpful. Thanks in advance

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  directoryservice:
    image: abc-directoryservice:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - "44309:44309"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:44309;
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=welcome123#
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./devops/https/abccert.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
      # - "$env:USERPROFILE/source:$env:USERPROFILE/source"
      - ${Env:USERPROFILE}\source:${Env:USERPROFILE}\source
```

I get below error

```
invalid interpolation format for services.directoryservice.volumes.[]: "${Env:USERPROFILE}\\source:${Env:USERPROFILE}\\source". You may need to escape any $ with another $.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$env:USERPROFILE`/ `${env:USERPROFILE}` syntax is *specific to PowerShell*.

Judging by [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/),  `docker-compose` uses its own syntax: `$USERPROFILE` / `${USERPROFILE}`

---

You report a *follow-up problem*, namely that the Windows-style path stored in `$USERPROFILE` (`%USERPROFILE%`) (e.g. `C:\Users\jdoe\source`) isn't converted to a Unix-style path (e.g. `c/Users/jdoe/source`)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216551/45375) suggests that you must set environment variable `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS`  to `1`, *before* running your `docker-compose` command.

E.g., in a PowerShell session:

```
$env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Consider adding this statement to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) so that it takes effect in future PowerShell sessions too.