# Docker-compose - volumes driver local meaning

Tags: docker

I'm making some docker-compose yml file with [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html). In this config, what does `driver: local` in top-level volumes mean?

```yaml
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
```

Comment: it seems local is the default driver, so it's redundant to specify it here

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's volume driver, equivalent to

```
docker volume create --driver local --name esdata1
docker volume create --driver local --name esdata2
```

`local` means the volumes esdata1 and esdata2 are created on the same Docker host where you run your container.
By using other Volume plugins, e.g.,

```
--driver=flocker
```

you are able to create a volume on a external host and mount it to the local host, say, `/data-path`. So, when your container writes to `/data-path`, it actually writes to a external disk via network.

Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#/volume-plugins) for some sort of Volume plugins available

Comment: does `local` refer to the directory where the docker-compose.yml file defining the volume lies, or some other default local directory? When I run `docker-compose up`, I don't see any local volumes or anything named esdata1 or esdata2. What am I missing here?

Comment: @topher217 When you install docker on your system it comes with a "docker root directory", and it's where containers, images or volumes normally stay. One way to see the volume details is to use `docker volume ls` and `docker volume inspect`