# Docker volume vs. persistent volume on official Docker beginner tutorial

Tags: docker

The tutorial is at [docker-curriculum](https://docker-curriculum.com/)

I am having trouble understanding the difference between volumes in this `docker-compose.yml` in the tutorial:

```
version: "3"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: es
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  web:
    build: . # replaced image with build
    command: python app.py
    environment:
      - DEBUG=True  # set an env var for flask
    depends_on:
      - es
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./flask-app:/opt/flask-app
volumes:
    esdata1:
      driver: local
```

There are `volumes` under `web`, `es` and then by itself with `esdata1:` and `driver: local` underneath it.  My newbie mind understands the ones under `web` and `es` to be mounts of external data to a directory within each container.  Then the last `volume` is putting a persistent volume on the host machine that will be there even when containers are killed.  In this case, it is `esdata1:` data that will persist.  My next question is, what does the `driver: local` mean?

Comment: please try search first before posting your question, sometimes someone is already asking the same question with an answer.....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195334/docker-compose-volumes-driver-local-meaning

Comment: @FendiD  Do you have any advice on how to search questions properly on this site?  I know there are ways to Google search terms using colons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just received advice from a mentor and yes, my guess is partially correct in that Docker will create a directory at `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and that directory can be mounted to containers.  This persistent volume becomes the location where data from processes inside containers, ie. MySQL, ElasticSearch, etc, is permanently stored. 
 (I'm guessing until you kill, delete everything with the `-v` option...just a guess).
The volume under `web` is the directory created by the programmer, ie. same subdirectory that contains `app.py` that is mounted in the container allowing rewrite of `app.py` on the fly, ie. whatever changes are made on the local machine are reflected in the container.
As a newbie to containers and Docker, this all seems very efficient although the learning curve is somewhat steep for me.  Please see above comments with link to another question for answer to the second question.