# How to mount a folder from my host to a custom docker image, setup using Dockerfile in a directory?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, containers

My Dockerfile path: `/home/kshitij/docker/php_apache_5.6/Dockerfile`

I have apache installed on my host pc and it has files in `/var/www/html` directory.

Now, I want to mount this directory from **host pc** (`/var/www/html`) to my **docker container's** `/var/www/html` directory.

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount host directory in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23439126/608639), [How to mount host volumes into docker containers in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26050899/608639), [How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40905761/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to mount a volume. Check out this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Example:

```
$ docker run -d \
    --name container-name \
    -v /var/www/html:/var/www/html \
    nginx:latest
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have a custom image in a directory so this will not work as the absolute path will start from Dockerfile directory.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by custom image in a directory? Typically volumes have nothing to do with a Dockerfile nor the directory it's sitting in. Just provide an absolute path from your file system

Comment: Tried it again with different options. Still not working. The absolute path always starts from the Dockerfile directory.

Comment: I was using the wrong command. I was mounting volume after image name.