# How to copy files from docker container to host using docker-compose in docker-machine

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

I have reports generated in gradle container for my selenium tests, I am trying to copy the files from docker container to local host. As a work around, I have used docker cp to copy files from container to my local and it works. How to achieve it with docker-compose volumes.

Below is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3 "
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub_compose
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    container_name: selenium-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "5900"
    environment:
      - http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:83
      - https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:83
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  gradle:
   image: gradle:jdk8
   container_name: selenium-gradle
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
```

I run the command `docker-compose up` -> it runs the selenium tests and generates the report in the container.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Power off the machine in Virtual box -> Change the Advanced settings in Virtual box
2. Goto Shared Folders in Virtual box 
   Give Path :: C:\DockerResults : Give a logical name for the Folder name
3. Restart the machine in DockerTerminal with the below command
   docker-machine restart default
4. After machine is started open the Virtual box
   Create a directory in the Virtual machine : sudo mkdir /Results
5. Mount the directory to the local windows machine by executing the below command in virtual box: 
   Sudo mount –t vboxsf DockerResults /Results
6. Add volumes as below in docker-compose file

volumes:

```
    - /DockerResults:/home/Reports/
```

Answer (score 5):

The normal way to pass data from container to host is using docker volumes.
In short you specify a host directory and map it to the directory inside container. And that directory should be used to save your test reports

```
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub_compose
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - ./path/to/report/folder:/host/reports
```

- See docker documentation
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver
- Similar question:
  [How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905761/how-do-i-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-compose)

Comment: `code`
gradle:
   image: gradle:jdk8
   container_name: selenium-gradle
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
volumes:
       - ./Result:/C/Users/**/Volume

Comment: for Windows you may have to set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 env. variable plus you may have to do some configurations as expressed here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/ I have no experience with running docker for Windows so can't help here :(

Comment: I use dokcer-machine not docker for windows. is there any link which would help it better

Comment: I suppose this: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-share-volumes-and-or-drives-using-docker-machine-on-windows-not-beta/20170 please try /c/Users/ as mentioned there

Comment: I have tried creating a mount and mapped the volumes in docker compose, it creates the .gradle folder in the local directory and searches for the gradle tasks. Not sure how to work it out

Comment: Ok. What is the content of your ./Result folder inside the selenium-hub container?

Comment: It creates a .gradle folder inside the ./Result in windows and /C/Users/**/Volume is created in the container root folder.

Comment: @Ashwinsathyanarayanancan you update your question with the latest changes please?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. Do you know where the test results are stored inside your docker container? Is it ./Result?

Comment: @Akceptor Result are stored in ./Result folder inside the container

Comment: And are you saying that the content of ./Result is not present in c/Users/**/Volume outside

Comment: @Akceptor Results are not copied to the local machine  c/Users/**/Volume

Comment: @Ashwin could you please try different order? I.e. 
 - c/Users/**/Volume:./Result

Comment: I have tried all that, c/Users/**/Volume folder is created inside the roor folder of container

Comment: I looked thru docker documentation and it seems ok but there are lots of issues mentioned for windows users. Please check if something from here helps: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2548 and https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox/issues/175

Comment: Also please check if you have your c drive listed as shared drive https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

Comment: c drive is listed in shared drive

Comment: I have the same issue that I have created the volume but it is empty and still, the results are in the result folder in the container is there an option to run a command in either the docker file or the docker-compose.yml file to copy the reports from the results folder in the container to the volume folder which appears as an empty folder inside the container after running - it seems that the volume option passes the data from the host to container, not vice versa

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is wrong. Unlike named volumes bind mounts won't copy the container contents to the host automatically. [Link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-wont-copy-files-into-local-volume/116191/2?u=aderchox) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176940/a-bind-mount-wont-copy-the-container-contents-to-the-host-automatically-unlik)