# How to mount to lowerdir (overlayfs)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, overlay, overlayfs, docker-overlay2

I need to include some PHP code in the docker image and at the same time use some code from host directory while maintaining a certain file structure inside the running container.

How to write mount of hostdir1 in docker-compose.yml file correctly?

Let me explain with a short example:

1. inside image (after build):

> ```
> tree /mount
> mount/
> ├── 1.txt
> ├── 4.txt
> └── 5.txt
> ```

```
 cat mount/1.txt 
 internal
```

2. on the host filesystem:

> ```
> hostdir1/
> ├── 1.txt
> ├── 2.txt
> └── somedir
>     └── 3.txt
> ```

```
 cat hostdir1/1.txt
 external
```

3. I need to mount host folder to contaider using smth like overlayFS and get the following file structure in the running container:

> ```
> mount/
> ├── 1.txt
> ├── 2.txt
> ├── 4.txt
> ├── 5.txt
> └── somedir
>     └── 3.txt
> ```

```
cat mount/1.txt 
internal
```

Upd: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905761/how-do-i-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-compose) They simply mount the directory into the container, overwriting all the contents of the directory in the image. I need to mount the host directory from below to the desired image directory. Keeping available all the files that are in the image and adding to them those files and directories that are on the server but are not in the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905761/how-do-i-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-compose)

Comment: Thank ypu for quick reply. But no.
They simply mount the directory into the container, overwriting all the contents of the directory in the image. I need to mount the host directory, as it were, from below to the desired image directory. Keeping available all the files that are in the image and adding to them those files that are on the server but are not in the image.

Comment: @BMitch could you help please? need to mount hostdir to container as a lowerdir