# Run a python script with input args on docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and super frustrated on how to do this. The main idea is to run a python script that takes two numbers and create a xls file, with those numbers, in the directory where the terminal is open. But I want to run this on docker, so that everytime I need to run this just need to do `$ docker-compose up 2numbers`.

main.py

```py
import pandas as pd

number1 = int(input('Please enter number 1: '))
number2 = int(input('Please enter number 2: '))

data = {
    "number1": number1,
    "number2": number2,
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /main

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt:

```
pandas==2.1.4 
numpy==1.26.3
openpyxl==3.1.2
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  2numbers:
    build:
      context: .
    image: '2numbers'
    container_name: 'container_2numbers'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/main
    command: python main.py
```

I think the problem must be in the volumes or in the docker-compose options, because the container keeps on running but never calls the script main.py

Tried different volume paths

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount a host directory as a volume in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905761/how-do-i-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-compose)

Comment: If you need interactive input, and the primary goal of your application is to write a file on the host system, you might find it substantially easier to run without Docker.  Most Linux and MacOS systems already have Python preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered passing your two numbers via environmental variables?

You'd then be able to fall back to a more classic `docker-compose.yml`.

```
NUM1=number1 NUM2=number2 docker compose up -d --build
```

And you'd just have to call `os.environ['NUM1']` in your python code to access it.

Comment: In this case it must be through the inputs in the script